# Cordova and localhost for iOS

Tags: cordova, http, localhost, cordova-plugins

I try to have Cordova serving my application via localhost instead of file:// for iOS (11.3) but cannot manage to find a plugin up to date to do that.

I tried https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine with `<content src="http://localhost/index.html" />` in may `config.xml` file.

I tried Cordova-httpd but it seems abandoned for a year and while I try to install it, this is what I get :

```
(node:4165) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd.git via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! package.json Non-registry package missing package.json: git+https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd.git.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/gomoon/.npm/_logs/2018-04-04T14_48_24_009Z-debug.log
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:173:37
    at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:864:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:890:30
    at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:1142:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:808:41)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)
(node:4165) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4165) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

So any plugin or tip would unstuck me on this.

Answer (score 4):

I too found it hard to understand how to get Cordova to run smoothly on iOS. Guess I'm 5 months late trying to answer this question but I'll do my best anyways for others surfing in to this question.

I got it to run smoothly with my Single Page App (ReactDOM) using the the plugin *cordova-labs-local-webserver*. 
*cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine* works great together with *cordova-labs-local-webserver* which will give you access to your www folder using http://localhost/ in your Cordova project.

You can find the plugin at apache's official repo for experimental plugins: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins. The repo has several plugins maintained by Apache. Each plugin is located within its own branch. The branch named *local-webserver* contains the plugin *cordova-labs-local-webserver*. Once you've installed the plugin you can add the following to the config.xml file in order to serve your content from http://localhost/ inside your Cordova app:

```
<content src="http://localhost:0" />
```

Note that port 0 will give you a random port each time you start your app. Please see the readme.md for more info ([readme.md](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/blob/local-webserver/README.md)).

I had issues installing the plugin due to fetching issues. I think it was because I needed to add the --fetch parameter to the *cordova plugin add* command. I eneded cloning the repo and installing it from a directory on my machine.
However. Before doing that. Try:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins#local-webserver
```

that will fetch the plugin directly from the repo branch *local-webserver*. 
If that doesn't work. Try

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins#local-webserver --fetch
```

Now I wish you the best of luck installing the plugin. However, if you are unlucky as I was you can install the plugin in a less confortable way by cloning the repo from Github to a folder on your local machine and switch the branch from master to local-webserver. Once you have the plugin source code on you machine you can install the plugin using the following commmand:

```
cordova plugins add {directory to the local-webserver branch folder}
```

An issue doing so is that your cordova project will always be looking for the source code from that folder whenever you want to add a platform using the plugin.

THE OPTIMAL SOLUTION
If you wish to install fetch and install the cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine plugin AND the cordova-labs-local-webserver with one command you might be interested in trying the *wkwebview-engine-localhost* plugin located in the same repo. It simply fetches the cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine as well as the cordova-labs-local-webserver plugin at the same time. Try:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins#wkwebview-engine-localhost
```

and if that doesn't work...

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins#wkwebview-engine-localhost --fetch
```

Good luck anyone who stumbles accross this post :)
Happy to discuss and edit this answer if someone has any suggestions.